# Return only value of listed index from an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to filter an array based on the listed index in another array.
For example:

```
const item = ['apple','orange','watermelon','pineapple'];
const index = [1,3];
```

Based on the index array , I want to return an array of `[ 'orange','pineapple']`

How do I do that in an efficient way? I tried using comparison between 2 array , but i think it is not very good for efficiency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do `map` over the `index` array and just do a regular indexing to look up the item from the `item` array.

```
const result = index.map(idx => item[idx]);
```

No need for comparisons when you already have the indices. You just access them directly instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following,

```
const res = [];
item.forEach((item, idx) => { if(index.includes(idx)) res.push(item); });
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Your output `[undefined, "orange", undefined, "pineapple"]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

`const filteredArray = index.map(i => item[i]);`

Output:

[image]